# Compiling Assets in Ruby does it need to be done in deployment? Why not before?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets, precompile

So this is just a question I've been wondering about lately, I seem to spend a significant amount of time when deploying waiting for assets to compile.

Why can we not compile the assets on our development machines and submit it in the git repo?

I am currently using ruby 2.5.x and rails 5.2.4.x using the assets pipeline with uglifier.

Is there a way to do this in development and thus disable all asset compilation during deployment?

many thanks,
Simon

Comment: You can do that. But then you need to re-compile and restart the server every time you do a minor change while developing your appl. This would be certainly very annoying while implementing features...

Comment: I am trying to avoid doing any compilation on the server to make deployments faster. I spend a lot of time waiting for assets to compile when deploying code, so I was thinking could it be done once in development, pushed into git, so when deploying the servers do not need to do anything with assets. I don't want to do any re-compiling or restarting the servers, so is that not possible?

Comment: To add some more detail to my query I am using aws elastic beanstalk and with low ram vm's the compilation time for assets was sometimes over an hour or it would simply run out of memory and fail. I have hundreds of instances of elastic beanstalk and is a real pain with assets on each deploy of new software.

Comment: Another reason why you might want to do this is if you are on **Docker**. On Docker you usually have your DB in a different Container, so the DB isn't available while your app Docker Image gets built. If you try compiling the assets in the app's Dockerfile you need to use a dirty hack to fool Rails into thinking the DB is present. This is because `rails assets:precompile` loads the Rails environment, so initializers get executed, and those often try to connect to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple

1) disable asset compiling during deployment

I'm using elastic beanstalk so just had to set this in the environment variables
[image: Elastic Beanstalk Asset Compilation]
2) Either

- Add the /public/assets folder to git
- Or for elastic beanstalk create .ebignore file and copy over the .gitignore but remove the /public/assets entry

3) before deploying run

- Linux -- RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
- Windows -- set RAILS_ENV=development && bundle exec rake assets:precompile

4) deploy code to server as normal

- eb deploy

Answer (score 1):

1st: `Why can we not compile the assets on our development machines and submit it in the git repo?`

The reason why we need to precompile are:

- Compressed the assets resources then cached some static content like images, css and so on.

It's help us to generates two files (.css and .js) and compressed all our's css file event it's file from vendors:

```
<script src="/assets/application-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.js"></script>
<link href="/assets/application-4dd5b109ee3439da54f5bdfd78a80473.css" media="screen"
rel="stylesheet" />
```

It's very helpful but `It's take time` and `And the resource it not live reload when you modify some code. You have to re-compile to apply the code.

-> So, That's why you should not compile the assets in DEVELOPMENT evironment.

2nd: `Is there a way to do this in development and thus disable all asset compilation during deployment?`
You also use precompile on DEVELOPMENT by run this command:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

You can precompile assets in development environment by default using
 config/development.rb

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

Thanks. Hope it's help

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I precompile before deployment, commit, and push it to Github, as you mentioned.
Then, I deploy to production with `capistrano` gem: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano

This is the command to precompile:

```sh
rails assets:precompile
```